# An equation in the convolution measure algebra on reals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let us consider the measure algebra $M(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all Radon measures on reals.
Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure in  $M(\mathbb{R})$ and $\delta_0$ be the point mass measure concentrated on 0,  which is also the multiplicative identity of $M(\mathbb{R})$.

> Q. Does there exist any strictly positive real number $r>0$ and Radon measures  $\mu_1,\cdots \mu_n$ satisfying the following idenity? $$\mu^**\mu=r\delta_0+\sum_1^n\mu_i^**\mu_i.$$

Remark. $M(\mathbb{R})=C_0(\mathbb{R})^*$ is a unital dual Banach $*$-algebra. The involution on $M(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as follow
$$\langle \mu^*,f\rangle=\int f(t)\overline{d\mu(-t)}.$$

Comment: What is $\mu^*$ here? What is $n$? Whatever $\mu^*$ means, can't you just take here $r=0$, $n=1$, $\mu_1=\mu$? Or, more generally, $r=0$, $\mu_1=\mu$, and $\mu_2=\cdots=\mu_n=0$?

Comment: @ 
Iosif Pinelis  Some more details are added.

Comment: @ 
Iosif Pinelis  As I made some correction,  the scaler $r$ should be considered non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no in general. Indeed, let $\hat\mu$ denote the Fourier transform of $\mu$, so that $\hat\mu(t)=\int e^{itx}\mu(dx)$ for real $t$. Then the equality
$$\mu^**\mu=r\delta_0+\sum_1^n\mu_i^**\mu_i$$
would imply
$$|\hat\mu|^2=r+\sum_1^n|\hat\mu_i|^2\ge r>0.$$
Taking now any $\mu$ with $\hat\mu(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: I believe that this is the right viewpoint. But how do you define the Fourier transform $\hat\mu(t)$? the exponentials $e_t(x)=e^{itx}$ do not belong to $C_0(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth : Thank you for your comment. By the Riesz–Markov representation theorem for the continuous dual of $C_0(X)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X)), every $\mu\in C_0(\mathbb R)^*$ can be identified with a finite regular countably additive complex Borel measure. So, $\mu$ can be extended to the set of all bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, which allows one to define the Fourier transform of $\mu$.

Comment: Right, of course. Thanks.